# php multidimensional array as radio buttons with ID and array value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, radio-button

I am php noob. I have searched Google very thoroughly past couple of days and can't figure that out.

I have multidimensional array I have to convert to radio buttons with unique ID and values, but I can't seem to do it.

The json array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [available] => 1
                [courier] => 1
                [type] => 1
                [price] => 42.89
                [transitDays] => 3
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [available] => 1
                [courier] => 1
                [type] => 3
                [price] => 50.50
                [transitDays] => 4
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [available] => 0
            )

        ...

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [available] => 1
                [courier] => 2
                [type] => 1
                [price] => 111
                [transitDays] => 11
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [available] => 0
                [courier] => 2
                [type] => 4
                [price] => 22
                [transitDays] => 22
            )

        ...
    )
)
```

I need to make every output some of the values of every `['available']==1` array into radio buttons and on select be able to retrieve the data after form submission.

```
<p class="row"><input type="radio" id="option-<?php echo $i ?> value="service-<?php echo $i ?>" name="type" "> <?php echo $service['type']; ?> will cost <?php echo $service['price']; ?> and take <?php echo $service['days']; ?></p>
```

I have tried flattening arrays and spew available results, but I can't assign `unique ID's` then.
I tried

```
  foreach ($providers as $provider) {
  $mergeProvider = array_merge($provider);
  foreach ($provider as $services){
    $service = array_merge($services);
      if( $service['available'] == 0 ) { unset($service); }
      $serviceCount = count($service);
      else {
          include('offer.php'); //where is input type="button"
      }
```

but this does not allow me unique ID's.

If I do:

```
foreach ($providers as $provider) {
  $mergeProvider = array_merge($provider);
  foreach ($provider as $services){
    $service = array_merge($services);
        $serviceCount = count($services);
        for( $i = 1; $i < $serviceCount; $i++ ) {
        echo "<pre>";
        echo $serviceCount . "</pre>";
```

it spews out `$serviceCount` amount of different options where same option has different ID within it.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer to the question in your comment:

You mean how to map the service-10 back to the array?
You then you need a way to get the '10' from the string 'service-10'. But that can go wrong when the numbers become greater than 10. For example 110 (1 and 10).
So I've added another example of how to could do this. I've updated the code with a pipe to separate the $key and the $subkey:
$uniqueKey = $key . '|' . $subKey;

I've also added a var_dump so you can see the mapped data that it matches.

// for example, this is your index.php

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form id="theForm" name="theForm" method="POST" action="submit.php">
    <?php
    $items = array(
        0 => array(
            0 => array(
                "available" => 1,
                "courier" => 1,
                "type" => 1,
                "price" => 42.89,
                "transitDays" => 3
            ),
            1 => array(
                "available" => 1,
                "courier" => 1,
                "type" => 3,
                "price" => 50.50,
                "transitDays" => 4
            ),
        ),
        1 => array(
            0 => array(
                "available" => 1,
                "courier" => 2,
                "type" => 1,
                "price" => 111,
                "transitDays" => 11
            ),
            1 => array(
                "available" => 0,
                "courier" => 2,
                "type" => 4,
                "price" => 22,
                "transitDays" => 22
            ),
        )
    );

    foreach($items as $key => $item) {
        foreach($item as $subKey => $subItem) {
            if ($subItem["available"] === 1) {
                $uniqueKey = $key . '|' . $subKey;
                echo sprintf(
                    '<p class="row"><input type="radio" id="option-%1$s" value="service-%1$s" name="type">%2$s will cost %3$s and take %4$s</p>',
                    $uniqueKey,
                    $subItem["type"],
                    $subItem["price"],
                    $subItem["transitDays"]
                );
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

For example this is your submit.php

```
<?php
$items = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => array(
            "available" => 1,
            "courier" => 1,
            "type" => 1,
            "price" => 42.89,
            "transitDays" => 3
        ),
        1 => array(
            "available" => 1,
            "courier" => 1,
            "type" => 3,
            "price" => 50.50,
            "transitDays" => 4
        ),
    ),
    1 => array(
        0 => array(
            "available" => 1,
            "courier" => 2,
            "type" => 1,
            "price" => 111,
            "transitDays" => 11
        ),
        1 => array(
            "available" => 0,
            "courier" => 2,
            "type" => 4,
            "price" => 22,
            "transitDays" => 22
        ),
    )
);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['type'])) {
        $type = $_POST['type'];
        $positionDash = strpos($type, '-');
        $positionPipe = strpos($type, '|');
        if (false !== $positionDash && false !== $positionPipe) {
            $tail = substr($type, $positionDash+1);
            $tree = explode('|', $tail);
            $mappedData = $items[$tree[0]][$tree[1]];
            var_dump($mappedData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why am I getting NULL all the time. Everything seems to work up until $mappedData

Comment: Just checking,  did you copy all the code or only the part where the post values are being checked?  I've also changed the way the $uniqueKey is being created.

Comment: Just to be sure, I've replaced the code with a test setup. Can you tell me if this setup works on your machine?

Comment: The test is working fine now, but it gives me null whenever I copy `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
       ...
            }
        }
    }`

 to another file for `action="submit.php"`, which is odd

Comment: When you are posting to another file (in your case submit.php), you should also copy the $items array to submit.php . On the first page you are generating the selectboxes using the $items array as the data source. When you post to another file and try to map the posted data back, that other file should also have the data source to which you are trying to map it.

Comment: I did `$items = json_decode(json_encode($input), true);` and `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { ... } } }`, but it appears that it is not a copy, since I still receive NULL

Comment: I've updated the example with the code for an 'index.php' and the code for a 'submit.php'. Does that work in your case?

Comment: I passed array using session cookie, and it works the best! Thanks a lot for your help! You are great!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a unique key based on the keys of the foreach loops.

Then when you post the form, the name field will contain a unique value like service-00, service-01, service-10

For example:

```
$items = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => array(
            "available" => 1,
            "courier" => 1,
            "type" => 1,
            "price" => 42.89,
            "transitDays" => 3
        ),
        1 => array(
            "available" => 1,
            "courier" => 1,
            "type" => 3,
            "price" => 50.50,
            "transitDays" => 4
        ),
    ),
    1 => array(
        0 => array(
            "available" => 1,
            "courier" => 2,
            "type" => 1,
            "price" => 111,
            "transitDays" => 11
        ),
        1 => array(
            "available" => 0,
            "courier" => 2,
            "type" => 4,
            "price" => 22,
            "transitDays" => 22
        ),
    )
);
```

// then loop through the $items and create unique key

```
foreach($items as $key => $item) {
    foreach($item as $subKey => $subItem) {
        if ($subItem["available"] === 1) {
            $uniqueKey = $key . $subKey;
            echo sprintf(
                '<p class="row"><input type="radio" id="option-%1$s" value="service-%1$s" name="type">%2$s will cost %3$s and take %4$s</p>',
                $uniqueKey,
                $subItem["type"],
                $subItem["price"],
                $subItem["transitDays"]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoa! That is what I needed to start my workweek! I wouldn't be able to come up with this on my own, yet! Thanks!

But I have a question now - what next can I do with received value? How can I assign according array to that value?

Comment: I've added an answer to your question.